# What is the meaning of Directivity and Reflection coefficient for a RX antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, microwave

it's known that the circuital models of TX and RX antennas are the following ones:

[image]

They are fine, but I find it hard to understand the meaning of some concepts when applied at the RX case. For instance:

**1) INPUT REFLECTION COEFFICIENT**
In TX case, the antenna input reflection coefficient quantifies the reflected power at the input port because of an impedance mismatch between the source impedance Zg and the antenna impedance Za. The reflected power goes towards the source, while the difference between incident and reflected power goes into the antenna and is radiated (or, in part, accumulated in antenna parasitic reactances).

But, what does it represent in RX case? Even in this case it describes a mismatch between the other circuit (here called ZL, but suppose it's equal to Zg) and the antenna impedance. So, I'd say that the difference between incident and reflected power goes to the load circuit ZL. But where does the reflected power go in RX case? In theory, it should come back to the surrounding space of the antenna... but it seems quite strange.

**2) DIRECTIVITY**
The directivity of a TX antenna is the ratio between the power radiated per solid angle of our antenna and of an isotropic antenna. What is its meaning in case of a RX antenna? Is it ratio the incident power (power induced on antenna conductors by the time-varying incident Electric and Magnetic fields) on the antenna? Is the directivity the same in TX and RX?

Comment: Remember the fund. theorem of antennas: RX and TX are dual and the same. For directivity you are exactly right, the antenna is more sensitive in the same direction it emits better. As for the antenna reflecting into space it isn't strange, many antenna have elements which are called reflectors just for that property

Comment: @user287001 "50% of the RF energy … is immediately radiated back" that is um... wrong. Where do you take that from?

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio the "reflection coefficient" has nothing to do with the antenna having a reflector, but with impedance matching on the antenna feed (input).

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank's for the notice. 50% re-radiation is true only if there's no losses and the antenna is matched with the receiver. The clause was based on the common equivalent circuit which contains a source for induced EMF , radiation impedance, loss resistance and load impedance, It was a hole between the ears. I removed the wrong comment.

Comment: @user287001  "50% re-radiation is true only if there's no losses and the antenna is matched with the receiver.", no that's simply not the case. That perfect antenna with perfect matching simply absorbs 100% of the energy hitting its effective area, and forwards it to the receiver. I don't know the *common equivalence circuit* you're referring to, could you link me to it?

Comment: Such antenna is nonexistent. How it could separate current caused by the catched radiation and possible simultaneously connected transmitter which is matched and connected in place of the receiver?

Comment: @user287001 I don't know your mental model of an antenna, and I don't see how any transmitter comes into play. And: antennas close to 100% efficiency do exist. Think about a horn antenna: It just converts the free-space wave to a wave in a waveguide. The wave still transports energy only "forward". Maybe thinking of all antennas as impedance matchers from free space wave impedance to transmission line impedance helps?

Comment: Hopefully you also fix this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_resistance#:~:text=In%20a%20receiving%20antenna%2C%20the,radio%20waves%20as%20when%20transmitting. My source is an antenna theory handbook written 50 years ago in our local tribal language.

Comment: @user287001 I know that wikipedia article quite well. Where does it claim you can't have more than 50% receive efficiency? Can you point me to the sentence or paragraph or even better equation?

Comment: There's paragraph "The power dissipated in the radiation resistance is due to radio waves reradiated (scattered) by the antenna.[7][8] Maximum power is delivered to the receiver when it is impedance matched to the antenna. If the antenna is lossless, half the power absorbed by the antenna is delivered to the receiver, the other half is reradiated.[7][8]"

Comment: @user287001 huh! Interesting, yeah, I missed that. I've checked the Balanis' book [8], which they link to in full text, and it doesn't say that where they claim it does. Maybe they are on the bogus mental model that the radiation resistance is like a series source impedance in a "classical" power supply? That doesn't work out – if that was the case, you're right, neither receive nor transmit antennas could have more than 50% efficiency \$\eta = \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}\$. However, since antennas with \$\gg 50\%\$ efficiency exist (and the wikipedia article on "antenna efficiency" confirms that),

Comment: I'm not sure how that assumption cooperates with reality.

Comment: @user287001 you know what? this is intriguing. Who of the two of us opens a question asking about exactly this?

Comment: I presented the 50% re-radiation without saying it's false if there's losses or mismatch. You told I wrote my own poetry. I noticed the obvious error and removed the wrong comment. You said "the error is totally elsewhere, a perfect antenna re-radiates nothing!" I wrote "no such antenna exists" and presented the common circuit model and the transmitter example (which is meaningful only if the common series circuit model is ok).

Comment: @MarcusMüller if the simple series circuit model of an antenna is OK then a superconductive antenna can well have 100% efficiency - as radiation efficiency. A voltage source feeds it.  If the simple series circuit model is invalid the situation is totally different. as well for receiving and transmitting. Can you point some easily accessible web sources for that case? The Goubau transmission line suggests that the simple series equivalent circuit can only a partial truth.

Comment: ah wait, the conductivity of the antenna material has nothing to do with the radiation resistance! But sure, I think the book by Balanis linked at the very bottom of the wikipedia article is a good resource. In fact, it's *the* classic on antennas!

Comment: Jumping in a little late, but that 50% loss claim due to re-radiation is bogus.  I know that when our antenna folks do their sensitivity analysis, there's no 3 dB (6 dB if this is a voltage phenomena) loss in the equation for this re-radiation phenomenon.  Simplistically, they take the power density (dBm/cm^2), multiply it by the "capture" area of the element, convert that to a voltage using a 50 ohm impedance, and go from there.

Comment: @SteveSh how you did get confirmed that their capture area didn't take into the account the claimed re-radiation? The calculation method alone doesn't make the re-radiation non-existent. The re-radiation is based on the assumption that an antenna should have the same Thevenin equivalent no matter is it connected to a receiver or to something that can transmit.

Comment: @user287001 9 - I'll have to dig into my reference material a bit more.  But if what you're saying is correct, wouldn't that mean that on transmit, half the input power is reflected back to the transmitter/amplifier?  And I know that doesn't happen, at least under normal operating conditions.

Comment: The transmitter output (cable is seen as a part of transmitter) sees in series  loss resistance, antenna radiation resistance, antenna reactance and a voltage source which presents what the antenna has catched from elsewhere than from the transmitter. That doesn't cause reflection back to the transmitter.if the matching has done ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a long discussion in comments. Here's some echoes.

You use the common series equivalent circuit for the  antenna. It's the Thevenin equivalent. If we assume that the equivalent circuit is valid then the radiation resistance can be shown to exist also when an antenna receives and it should re-radiate (=scatter) 50% of the catched power if nothing is dissipated in resistive losses and the load (=line+receiver) are exactly matched to the antenna. More re-radiation can be got by having mismatched load and that extra can be calculated with the reflection factor you asked. An open or shorted receiver end of the antenna reflects everything back and that is radiated to the space if nothing is dissipated in resistive losses.

The said automatic 50% minimum re-radiation power in lossless case can be found in numerous antenna theory writings including Wikipedia and the book of Balanis which is referenced in comments. The book is freely readable here https://archive.org/details/Antenna.Theory.Analysis.and.Design3rd.Edition/page/n97/mode/1up

The 50% re-radiation is presented in page 85 (by the original page numbering, not the web reader numbering).

Not everyone accept the idea that well matched lossless antennas should re-radiate 50% of the catched RF power. But it must happen if we accept that an antenna should have the same simplistically deduced Thevenin equivalent circuit, no matter is it connected to a passive load or to a device which maybe also transmits something.

How to present Thevenin (or Norton) equivalent of receiving antenna without that obscure automatic re-radiation? Some people seem to want that the receiver should see an equivalent circuit which outputs what's really captured. Some scientific papers are published of the problem. Here's links to 2 of them. The first one is free (or pirated), but full of cryptic math: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.205.6066&rep=rep1&type=pdf

I unfortunately haven't good enough math skills to judge the calculations and how well it succeeds to get over the automatic 50% re-radiation. Maybe someone with the needed skills could give a comprehensive explanation for practical electricians.

The text has in its end a long list of references to earlier  texts of the same problem.

The second one must be purchased (I do not have it): https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1203128

**Directivity** is connected with the effective catching area of the antenna. For the radiation which comes from the most sensitive direction of the antenna the effective catching area Ae = G((wavelength)^2 )/(4Pi) where G=the gain. The catched power is the wave intensity (watts/square meter) multiplied by Ae.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I have collected an answer which contains links to some stuff which do not see the re-radiation as trivial as I have believed it is.

Comment: Thanks! I'm too late to the game it seems :(

Comment: Not at all - especially if you have a possibility  to interpret the result in the linked writing https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.205.6066&rep=rep1&type=pdf For me it contains too much vector field integrals and indexed (tensor looking, but probably still something simpler) variables.